# Difficulties when positioning DIV tags

Tags: css, position, html

I'm pretty new to css styling and I need help postioning DIVs in a layout. If a DIV tag is declared bottom of the page, when the browser width is reduced (to simulate as in a mobile phone), I require this DIV to be displayed on top. I know this could be achieved by assigning a minus value, but isn't there a better way of doing this?

Please have a look at the http://2010.dconstruct.org/speakers/tom-coates and notice that the content inside the right column is displayed before the main content when the browser width is reduced. I'm unable to find the solution through firebug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They use media queries:

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 767px), all and (max-width: 449px){
    // Code
}
```

If you want to know more about them, you can read, e.g., http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a CSS @media query to condition different CSS rules on the width of the page already.

What I would do is, put the div in question before the main content in the HTML document, and above your width threshold, have it float: right. Then, below your width threshold, do not have it floating right.